# Where does Elise land when casting rappel?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does she land behind the enemy champion, or perhaps always the closest distance to where she rappeled up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elise lands directly on her target. But if the target moves she will still land where it stood before. [See the Lol Wiki description](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elise/Ability_Details)

Answer (score 1):

Elise will land at the location of a targeted champion if Rappel is cast with a target, or if it is recast on a target while she is in the air. If Rappel is cast without a target, she will lift for 2 seconds and return to the same spot she was lifted from once the spell concludes.